# TypeScript exports is not defined, tried all amelioration techniques

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have checked all the StackOverflow answers on this issue of the typescript exports not being defined and none of them ameliorate the issue.

I am following a youtube tutorial and the guy in the video has no issue.

In `tsconfig.json` I have set target to ES6 and commented out the module.
Then I have tried setting module to commonjs this did not work as well. EDIT: Set module to ES6 still does not work.

In `index.html` I have set the script type to module and also tried the trick with
`<script>var exports = {"__esModule": true};</script>` but with no luck, if I do this I get require is not defined.

sandbox.ts:

```
import { Invoice } from './classes/Invoice';

const form = document.querySelector('.new-item-form') as HTMLFormElement; 

//inputs
const type = document.querySelector('#type') as HTMLSelectElement;
const tofrom = document.querySelector('#tofrom') as HTMLInputElement;
const details  = document.querySelector('#details') as HTMLSelectElement;
const amount  = document.querySelector('#amount') as HTMLSelectElement;

form.addEventListener('submit', (e:Event) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(
        type.value,
        tofrom.value,
        details.value,
        amount.value
    );
});


//instantiate class
const invOne = new Invoice('test', 'work on test', 250);

console.log (invOne);

let invoice:Invoice[] = []; //only accepts invoice objects in the array
invoice.push(invOne);

interface isPerson{
    name:string;
    age:number;
    speak(a: string):void; //takes a string parameter and returns void
    spend(a:number):number;
}

const me:isPerson = {
    name:"PersonName",
    age:30,
    speak(text:string):void{
        console.log(text);
    },
    spend(amount: number): number {
        console.log('I spent', amount);
        return amount;
    }

    //Adding more properties won't work because they are not inside the interface
}

console.log(me);
```

Invoice.ts (the class I am trying to import):

```
export class Invoice{
    readonly client:string;
    private details:string;
    public amount:number;

    constructor(c:string,d:string,a:number) {
        this.client = c;
        this.details = d;
        this.amount = a;
    }

    //Method
    format(){
        return `${this.client} owes £${this.amount} for ${this.details}`;
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TypeScript Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Finance Logger</h1>

    <!-- output list -->
    <ul class="item-list">

    </ul>
</div>

<footer>
    <form class="new-item-form">
        <div class="field">
            <label>Type:</label>
            <select id="type">
                <option value="invoice">Invoice</option>
                <option value="payment">Payment</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>To / From:</label>
            <input type="text" id="tofrom">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Details:</label>
            <input type="text" id="details">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Amount (£):</label>
            <input type="number" id="amount">
        </div>
        <button>Add</button>
    </form>

    <a href="https://www.thenetninja.co.uk">The Net Ninja</a>
</footer>

<!-- <script>var exports = {"__esModule": true};</script> -->
<script type="module" src='sandbox.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Added sandbox.js content

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var Invoice_1 = require("./classes/Invoice");

var form = document.querySelector('.new-item-form');

var type = document.querySelector('#type');
var tofrom = document.querySelector('#tofrom');
var details = document.querySelector('#details');
var amount = document.querySelector('#amount');
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(type.value, tofrom.value, details.value, amount.value);
});

var invOne = new Invoice_1.Invoice('test', 'work on test', 250);
console.log(invOne);
var invoice = []; //only accepts invoice objects in the array
invoice.push(invOne);
var me = {
    name: "PersonName",
    age: 30,
    speak: function (text) {
        console.log(text);
    },
    spend: function (amount) {
        console.log('I spent', amount);
        return amount;
    }
    //Adding more properties won't work because they are not inside the interface
};
console.log(me);
```

Comment: You need tsconfig `module: es6`. Target is JS version it can run on, while module describes environment

Comment: @Dimava I still have the same issue even with module set to ES6

Comment: What's sandbox.js content?

Comment: Done edited the question to also include the contents of sandbox.js @Dimava

Answer (score 0):

For new devs like me into TypeScript I didn't know that you don't have to run the `tsc filename.ts` command each time you want to update the js file. You just have to do `tsc`. Besides that here is a configuration that a super helpful discord user (by the username of Ascor) gave me as well as the answer to my question.

Documentation regarding tsc command: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Configuration from Ascor:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "esnext", /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "dom"
        ], /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
        "module": "exnext", /* Specify what module code is generated. */
        "moduleResolution": "nodenext", /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
        "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true, /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
        "resolveJsonModule": true, /* Enable importing .json files. */
        "outDir": "./dist", /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
        "removeComments": true, /* Disable emitting comments. */
        "importHelpers": true, /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
        "isolatedModules": true, /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
        "esModuleInterop": true, /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */
        "strict": true, /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true, /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: you know of `--watch`? Write about that

Comment: Sure, but in my case at least this particular case I had no errors reported that's why I didn't write about it.